# Silverlight webservice call method direcly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, silverlight

```
var lockClient = new ServiceReference1.LockSoapClient();
lockClient.AcquireLockAsync();

bool status=true;
lockClient.AcquireLockCompleted += (s, e1) =>
{
     status = e1.Result;
};

sendStat(status);
```

I want to pass the the `boolean true/false` that i get from `e.Result` directly in sendStat() method. e.g. `sendStat(e1.Result)` I dont want to call this method inside the `lockClient.AcquireLockCompleted` section. How do I do it?

real example

```
Brush brush = GetPolygonFill(vectorPolygon, false, Settings.LightSourcePosition, adjust);
```

This

Settings.LightSourcePosition

portion need to come from webservice

Comment: `I dont want to call this method inside the lockClient.AcquireLockCompleted section.` Why not?

Comment: i agree with @Michael becouse service call is Async so that is not our control

Comment: Same here, why not, you need an async process for your callback, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to that outside of the completed method because of the async call. Anything inside the completed method is guaranteed to be executed once you have the results from your async call.